# Xaml ListView Programatically C# causing strange behavior

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin

I need to programmatically add a list view that dynamically changes... but I'm having a really odd layout that happens. I feel like I'm overlooking something. I need each row to show the shooter name, team name and their scores respectively. checkout the code. This has been edited to make it easier to read and figure out. Even with one single label of just shooter name It's having weird UI issues.

```
    private Grid grid = new Grid() { BackgroundColor = Color.White };
    private BoxView boxview = new BoxView() { BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray };
    private Grid grid2 = new Grid() { BackgroundColor = Color.White, Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 1), Padding = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0) };




        var shooterlabel = new Label() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start, Padding = PaddingLeft };
        shooterlabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Shooter_Name"));  

        grid2.Children.Add(shooterlabel, 0, 0);

        //grid.Children.Add(boxview);
        grid.Children.Add(grid2);

        ListView ShooterListView = new ListView() { BackgroundColor = Color.White, SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None, HasUnevenRows = true, VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Always };

        var ShooterDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            return new ViewCell { View = grid };
        });

        var connect = new ConnectionQuery("Select * From Shooters");
        var list = await connect.GetShooters();
        ShooterListView.ItemsSource = list;

        ShooterListView.ItemTemplate = ShooterDataTemplate;
        ShooterGrid.Children.Add(ShooterListView);

        connect.CloseConnection();
```

Below is a screenshot of what's happening. its supposed to be a name for each row. I'm only experiencing this issue in c# not in xaml. I have to have this working in code behind though...

[weird ui picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KAb5.png)

Attaching xaml below that does work with picture included.

```
 <StackLayout x:Name="Test">
            <Grid x:Name="ShooterGrid" >
                <ListView x:Name="ShooterListView" >
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Shooter_Name}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
               </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
```

attached below is the ui that is correct when done in xaml.

[Normal Ui Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9uRm.png)

Comment: Sorry, I could not see the picture

Comment: Its the blue hyperlink at the bottom apparently I dont have enough reputation to embed the image into the post https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBcCC.png  From what I can tell its almost like it created groups even though I have grouping disabled..

Comment: is there a reason you're not doing this in XAML?  Are you sure that your data is correct?

Comment: I cant do it in Xaml due to the number of columns changes based on the number of rounds pulled from the tournament in sql. The data binding worked but in a very strange way... Whenever I click a blank line all four of the labels change to whatever that blank line is supposed to be.. Instead of every shooter line by line

Comment: I think the problem relies on `grid2`: there is a padding that you have setted. Try to remove it and see if it helps

Comment: I removed all padding and styling and its still leaving huge white gaps in between. Also its duplicating the shootername. Its crazy almost like its placing them into grouping even though grouping isn't enabled

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `HasUnevenRows` to true to remove the space which you do not want.

The whold code:

```
public class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public static ObservableCollection<Names> names { get; set; }
    public Page1()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Names> names = new ObservableCollection<Names>()
        {
             new Names(){ Shooter_Name="Brain Palmer"},
             new Names(){ Shooter_Name="John Hagee"},
             new Names(){ Shooter_Name="Anget Jones"},
             new Names(){ Shooter_Name="Ron Kelly"},
             new Names(){ Shooter_Name="Jay Knight"},
             new Names(){ Shooter_Name="Jamie Redferm"},
             new Names(){ Shooter_Name="John Randolf"},
             new Names(){ Shooter_Name="Johnny Reddings"},
             new Names(){ Shooter_Name="Johnny john"},
             new Names(){ Shooter_Name="James Dun"},
             new Names(){ Shooter_Name="James Green"},
             new Names(){ Shooter_Name="Sunny Perdue"},
             new Names(){ Shooter_Name="John Gree"},
             new Names(){ Shooter_Name="Jamoe Parrott"},
        };

        ListView ShooterListView = new ListView() { HasUnevenRows = true };
        ShooterListView.ItemsSource = names;
        ShooterListView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            Grid grid = new Grid();


            Label NameLabel = new Label();

            NameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Shooter_Name");

            grid.Children.Add(NameLabel);
            return new ViewCell { View = grid };
        });
        //DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
        //dt.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, new Binding("Shooter_Name"));
        //ShooterListView.ItemTemplate= dt;


        Content = new StackLayout
        {

            Children = {
              ShooterListView
            }
        };

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}

public class Names
{
    public string Shooter_Name { get; set; }
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Have you check my code? The `HasUnevenRows` is easy to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I never could get the inline DataTemplate to work every time I used it the UI was completely messed up the grid used in the customviewcell is identical to the one I tried to set in the inline code.

The only solution was to create a custom view cell for each Round. Attaching below code and also one custom view cell example.

Code called to set the layout:

```
public async Task<ListView> SetShooterListView(int Rounds)
        {

            var shooterlistview = new ListView() { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill };

            var headergrid = Rounds == 1 ? await Get_Round_1() : Rounds == 2 ? await Get_Round_2() : Rounds == 3 ? await Get_Round_3() : Rounds == 4 ? await Get_Round_4() : Rounds == 5 ? await Get_Round_5() : Rounds == 6 ? await Get_Round_6() : Rounds == 7 ? await Get_Round_7() : Rounds == 8 ? await Get_Round_8() : Rounds == 9 ? await Get_Round_9() : await Get_Round_10();

            var viewcellgrid = Rounds == 1 ? new DataTemplate(typeof(Round_1_View)) : Rounds == 2 ? new DataTemplate(typeof(Round_2_View)) : Rounds == 3 ? new DataTemplate(typeof(Round_3_View)) : Rounds == 4 ? new DataTemplate(typeof(Round_4_View)) : Rounds == 5 ? new DataTemplate(typeof(Round_5_View)) : Rounds == 6 ? new DataTemplate(typeof(Round_6_View)) : Rounds == 7 ? new DataTemplate(typeof(Round_7_View)) : Rounds == 8 ? new DataTemplate(typeof(Round_8_View)) : Rounds == 9 ? new DataTemplate(typeof(Round_9_View)) : new DataTemplate(typeof(Round_10_View));            


            shooterlistview.Header = headergrid;


            shooterlistview.ItemTemplate = viewcellgrid;
            return shooterlistview;
           

        }
```

Custom View Cell Example:

```
    public class Round_7_View : ViewCell
    {
        private Thickness PaddingLeft;
        private Thickness PaddingRight;
        private Grid grid = new Grid() { BackgroundColor = Color.White };
        private BoxView boxview = new BoxView() { BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray };
        private Grid grid2 = new Grid() { BackgroundColor = Color.White, Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 1), Padding = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0) };

        public Round_7_View()
        {
            var column1 = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(15, GridUnitType.Star) };
            var column2 = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(15, GridUnitType.Star) };
            var column3 = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star) };
            var column4 = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star) };
            var column5 = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star) };
            var column6 = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star) };
            var column7 = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star) };
            var column8 = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star) };
            var column9 = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star) };

            var smallfont = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label));

            if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet || Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
            {
                PaddingLeft = new Thickness(20, 0, 0, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                PaddingLeft = new Thickness(60, 0, 0, 0);
            }


            if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet || Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
            {
                PaddingRight = new Thickness(0, 0, 20, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                PaddingRight = new Thickness(0, 0, 60, 0);
            }

            var shooterlabel = new Label() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start, FontSize = smallfont, Padding = PaddingLeft };
            shooterlabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Shooter_Name"));
            var team_name_label = new Label() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, FontSize = smallfont };
            team_name_label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Team_Name"));
            var round1_label = new Label() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, FontSize = smallfont };
            round1_label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Round_1"));
            var round2_label = new Label() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, FontSize = smallfont };
            round2_label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Round_2"));
            var round3_label = new Label() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, FontSize = smallfont };
            round3_label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Round_3"));
            var round4_label = new Label() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, FontSize = smallfont };
            round4_label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Round_4"));
            var round5_label = new Label() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, FontSize = smallfont };
            round5_label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Round_5"));
            var round6_label = new Label() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, FontSize = smallfont };
            round6_label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Round_6"));
            var round7_label = new Label() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End, FontSize = smallfont, Padding = PaddingRight };
            round7_label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Round_7"));

            grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column1);
            grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column2);
            grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column3);
            grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column4);
            grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column5);
            grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column6);
            grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column7);
            grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column8);
            grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column9);

            grid2.Children.Add(shooterlabel, 0, 0);
            grid2.Children.Add(team_name_label, 1, 0);
            grid2.Children.Add(round1_label, 2, 0);
            grid2.Children.Add(round2_label, 3, 0);
            grid2.Children.Add(round3_label, 4, 0);
            grid2.Children.Add(round4_label, 5, 0);
            grid2.Children.Add(round5_label, 6, 0);
            grid2.Children.Add(round6_label, 7, 0);
            grid2.Children.Add(round7_label, 8, 0);

            grid.Children.Add(boxview);
            grid.Children.Add(grid2);

            View = grid;
        }
    }
```